# using the ^ sign in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

Someone recently taught me a useful thing: in css you can write the following:

```
input[id^=start_of_name]
```

which will allow you to select all inputs with an id starting with 'start_of_name'. Can you do the equivalent for choosing the end of the name? The middle?

Comment: You should read the documentation for [CSS2 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html), followed by [CSS3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).

Comment: If it's something like a regexp thing, then it is possible, e.g. match from end using dollar ($), or match certain characters, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[att^=val]**
    Represents an element with the att attribute whose value begins with the prefix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

**[att$=val]**
    Represents an element with the att attribute whose value ends with the suffix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

**[att*=val]**
    Represents an element with the att attribute whose value contains at least one instance of the substring "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know how the put ^ in the search engine properly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings

> **[att^=val]** Represents an element with the att attribute whose value
>   begins with the prefix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the
>   selector does not represent anything.
>
> **[att$=val]** Represents an element
>   with the att attribute whose value ends with the suffix "val". If
>   "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent
>   anything.
>
> **[att*=val]** Represents an element with the att attribute
>   whose value contains at least one instance of the substring "val". If
>   "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent
>   anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is the complete list of CSS3 selectors: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

In your case, you are looking for E[foo$="bar"]

This matches an E element whose "foo" attribute value ends exactly with the string "bar"